CAB EOS5/300 prints only text over IP
I'm currently working with a company that lacquer plastic parts for the automotive sector. Every part needs to get a label printed by a label printer. The label printer we use is the CAB EOS5/300. We want to print over Ethernet instead of the serial RS-232. Officaly printing over TCP/IP is supported. When I connect the printer over the CAB driver with windows I can print, but instead of the correct label it only prints the raw JScript Text.
I'm having issues with the CAB EOS5/300. It is a label printer and is currently connected via RS-232 to USB. This works, but errors often occur because the conversion from USB to Serial fails or due to other issues unrelated to the machine or the printer, as both work perfectly fine. Now we want to use the EOS5/300 over RAW-IP or LPD/LPR. According to the manufacturer, the printer is able to print over TCP/IP/RAW-IP and LPD/LPR. However, when I connect the printer using the driver provided by the manufacturer over Ethernet, it doesn't print the label; instead, it prints the raw text. The raw text is written in JScript and looks like this:
mm
J
Sl1;0,0,68,71,100
H150,-2
T45,25,45,3,pt12;Wind
T45,25,315,3,pt12;mühlen
T45,25,225,3,pt12;mahlen
T45,25,135,3,pt12;Mehl
T44,42,90,3,4.5, b;für
T48,42,90,3,4.5, b;Brot
A1

You can find the documentation under https://www.cab.de/de/kennzeichnung/etikettensoftware/integration/integration/.
I have tried printing with the "Generic Text" option, and this was the output:
mTzTJO;AHTT;TBTDTS;T1T4m1lO421T4:4T:52310R5O5118581317C35U,,,.3R8,,,,,;,.86,P33990,006,I,03TO,.9G,,,1,.,9,.,9,,0,I0300FT000,,,00N,,00,,00F,,,,.30,,00,,130,,;3A33,,3,,,L,D,33,,3,32A3,,35;21,233,.T,,32.1,2.,.35333.832.2A.22.,03,.,33.,3.,M,,q,q33q5A3,,,33,q1q,q1q,,0T1,,710q,q,q,110001qR0,,00,011000I001105307;,,00;;;0;00,X0+0BD,;;D00;320;;RMDDU;H;,1U7..M0EHMOU6DDWD05M.D0M WMU3U A M,YM90YS6M1G5.qMYM 11,Y8 Y252q0+012C-0D1O;40[00ELS O;1DRUI8M,G0MINY.A254L;,H0D912D9U,,750MM0]Y09[YY]T[DOFY]0[CUTOFF]


As you can see, there's a big difference between the actual JScript and the printed text. Do you have any ideas on how to convert this text or get the correctly formatted text out of Windows?
Thanks in advance!
Kind regards,
Max
